# How to upload a very large file with Akka http client

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-http

I have a very large file(larger then my app heap size) on my local file system, and I'd like to send it within an HTTP request with Akka Http client.

How can i do this?

Comment: A possible solution is: you read the file as a stream and stream it up to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this:

```
Http(actorSystem).singleRequest( 
    HttpRequest(
      PUT,
      "http://example.com",
       headers,
       HttpEntity.fromPath(file_content_type, "PATH_TO_LARGE_FILE")
    )
)
```